# Ошибка из-за того, что элемент пока не существует

Tags: javascript, html

У меня на странице выводится таблица. Если в ней больше 3 строк, то средствами PHP в HTML также выводится кнопка "Показать ещё". Проблема в том, что сейчас у меня всего 2 строки, и поэтому в браузере я получаю ошибку: *Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelector(...) is null*

Урезанный код кнопки:

```
document.querySelector('#showmore').onclick = function() { 
    ...
}
```

И как мне быть, в случае, если я любитель делать всё в лучшем виде?
Только через оборачивание?:

```
if (document.querySelector('#showmore') !== null) {
    document.querySelector('#showmore').onclick = function() { 
    ...
}
```

Может есть способ получше?
*(без обходных путей по типу: "да просто выводи кнопку скрытой при любом количестве строк").*

Comment: Перенесите скрипт в документ, и пусть ваш PHP изменяет и его :)

Comment: Ну уж точно чего не стоит делать, так это 2 раза запрос `querySelector()`

Comment: А не проще ли вывести кнопку сразу с onclick  в кнопке?

Comment: @BearVorkuta не хочется js-код внутрь html совать, даже если это просто вызов функции.

Comment: @Михаил Тестов По сути то, что вы делаете через JS document.querySelector('#showmore').onclick и, как я предложил, навешивание атрибута onclick сразу в кнопке - вообще одно и тоже. Вызов функции через атрибут onсlick вполне нормально. Я бы понял если бы это был eventlistener, но тут разницы не вижу. А если уж правильно делать, как по мне, тогда генерируйте таблицу на фронте и сразу при проверке количества строк выводите кнопку и вешайте на нее событие. А то вы двойную проверку делаете сначала на php потом на js.

Comment: @BearVorkuta ну уж не знаю. На всем известном сайте написано, что: "HTML-атрибуты используются редко потому, что JavaScript в HTML-теге выглядит немного странно.". Кроме того, я считаю, что генерация таблицы на фронте это уже лишнее, слишком заморочено для небольшого проекта.

Answer (score 4):

Самый нормальный способ - это проверить явно:

```
const showMoreNode = document.querySelector('#showmore');

if (showMoreNode !== null) {
    showMoreNode.onclick = function() { 
    ...
}
```

Можно ещё сделать через делегирование событий:

```
document.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  if (target.matches('#showmore, #showmore *')) {
    console.log('hello');
  }
});
```

Или вообще через атрибут:

```
<button id="showmore" onclick="showMore()">Show more</button>
```

```
function showMore() {

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Если есть препроцессор или [новейшие браузеры только](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_operators_optional_chaining), то можно так:

```
document.querySelector('#showmore')?.addEventListener( 'click', ()=>{
   // ...
});
```

Comment: Как думаете, в противном случае, лучше использовать явную проверку существования, предложенную Ruslan Mart (ответ ниже) ?

Comment: Кстати, я также сумел придумать другое решение: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1255619/427513

Answer (score 2):

В порядке бреда так:

```
let button = document.querySelector('#showmore');
if (button)
{
  button.addEventListener('click', function(){
    ...
  });
}
```

Comment: А что бред, вполне себе решение) Но оно никогда не будет undefined (или объект, или null). Достаточно просто `if (button) { /* код */ }`

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий, подправил код. Писал в третьем часу ночи, потому и написал, что бред. )

Answer (score 2):

Пара извращенных функций для разнообразия)

*(Конечно, лучше использовать более простые решения, но кому-то было скучно)*.

1: Найти и вернуть элемент, если он есть, или создать (затратная операция!) и подсунуть div, чтобы избежать ошибки. Код применится к созданному div, который вскоре удалится из-за отсутствия ссылок на него.

```js
safe("#moo").addEventListener("click", Function);
safe("#foo").textContent = "ok";

function safe(selector) {
  return document.querySelector(selector) || document.createElement("div");
}
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
```

2: Разместить код, зависимый от селектора, в функцию:

```js
execFor("#foo", function() {
  // Весь ваш код, который должен запускаться только при наличии элемента.
  // this - найденный элемент.
  
  this.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log("Ура!");
  });
});

execFor("#moo", () => console.log("Не вызывается"));

/***/
function execFor(selector, fn) {
  let node = document.querySelector(selector);
  
  if (node && fn) fn.call(node);
  // Функция вызывается в контексте найденного элемента,
  // Но только если он существует.
  
  return node;
}
```

```html
<button id="foo"> Click </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Я, как автор вопроса, хочу спросить, как вам такое моё решение? :

```
const buttonShowMore = document.querySelector('#showmore') ? document.querySelector('#showmore') : new Object();
buttonShowMore('#showmore').onclick = function() { 
  ...
}
```

Или можно ещё короче:

```
(document.querySelector('#showmore') ? document.querySelector('#showmore') : {}).onclick = function() {
  ...
}
```

Или совсем коротко:

```
(document.querySelector('#showmore') || {}).onclick = function() {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Это плохие решения. Поиск элемента лучше делать один раз, и работать с найденным. Прочие ответы с `if( button )` и аналогами лучше. А в последнем лишние действия по созданию объекта и его метода.